# Oracle database table to use as an array to execute other query

Tags: sql, loops, oracle10g

I've been searching through books and the web for hours, and I couldn't find any real luck. As Oracle or PL/SQL isn't really my greatest gift in life I though to try it this way.

What I want to achieve is to select like all the records in TABLE A and use "each" record within a loop.

In pseudo code, it would be something like this.

x = SELECT * from TABLE_A;
for each x 
 UPDATE TABLE_B where kitten = x;
end for loop

Help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use cursor:

```
DECLARE
cursor c1 is
   select monthly_income
   from employees
   where name = v_name_in;
BEGIN
    FOR employee_rec in c1
    LOOP
         update tableB set incom_val = employee_rec.monthly_income where ...;
    END LOOP;
END;
```

or:

```
 DECLARE
    BEGIN
        FOR employee_rec in (select monthly_income
                                from employees
                                where name = v_name_in)
        LOOP
             update tableB set incom_val = employee_rec.monthly_income where ...;
        END LOOP;
    END;
```

Answer (score 4):

If possible, try to write it as a single UPDATE statement.

```
update table_b b
   set (b.col1, b.col2) = (
          select a.colx + 10, a.coly / 18
            from table_a a
           where b.id = a.id);
```

It is faster than the procedural counterpart and also has less lines of code making it easier to understand and migrate to other database.